# Why does Hyper-V virtualization depend on Windows Management Instrumentation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, hyper-v, wmi

In this experiment I disabled and deleted the Windows Management Instrumentation service in Windows 10 Pro 64bit. Do not try with your working PC. Here are the steps::

- Set dependency to only Remote Procedure Call (RPCSS) with reg command

For Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service (vmms):: `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmms" /v "DependOnService" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" /d "RPCSS" /f`

For Security Center service (wscsvc):: `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wscsvc" /v "DependOnService" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" /d "RPCSS" /f`

- Delete WMI service:: `sc stop "Winmgmt" & sc delete "Winmgmt"`

Then I restarted PC and the Hyper-V services show this error: Error 0x8007000e: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

[image: disable_Winmgmt]

Question: Why and how does the Hyper-V depend on WMI service?

Comment: we can't answer this. ask this Microsoft.

Comment: ask in Microsoft forums where MS employees read the questions.